# Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{|z-i|=R}\frac{z^{4}+z^{2}+1}{z(z^{2}+1)}dz$ as a function of $R>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I need to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int_{|z-i|=R}\frac{z^{4}+z^{2}+1}{z(z^{2}+1)} dz$ as a function of $R>0$. I may omit values of $R$ for which the denominator turns to $0$.

Now, using partial fraction decomposition, the integral can be split up as follows: $\displaystyle \int_{|z-i|=R} z \,dz + \int_{|z-i|=R}\frac{1}{z}\,dz-\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z-i|=R}\frac{1}{z+i}\,dz -\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z-i|=R} \frac{1}{z-i}\,dz$

Values for which the denominator of the non-decomposed function turns to $0$ include $R=1$ (when $R=1$, the curve intersects the singularity $z=0$) and $R=2$ (when $R=2$, the curve intersects the singularity $z=-i$).

Also, as $R$ grows to encompass all the singularities, the integral will go to $0$, by Cauchy's Theorem.

However, I am not really sure what to do with this problem. I tried actually parametrizing each integral, letting $|z-i|=R$ become $z = Re^{i \theta} + i$, but for the second and third integrals, I wound up getting $\ln|0|$, which is undefined. Anyway, this is not evaluating the integral as a function of $R$, but as a function of $z$ (or $\theta$).

Please help! Any help is needed, but any answers cannot use Residues or Cauchy's Integral Formula (Cauchy's Theorem for either simply or multiply connected domains is fine). And I would prefer something completely worked out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track using the parameterization $z=i+Re^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Here we present a way forward that uses real analysis by evaluating the real and imaginary parts of the integrals separately.  We will evaluate the integral $I$ given by

$$I=\oint_{|z-i|=R}\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz$$

and leave the evaluation of the original integral as an exercise.

---

**FIRST INTEGRAL**
For the first integral, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z-i|=R}\frac1z\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\theta}}{i+Re^{i\theta}}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R\cos(\theta)+iR(R+\sin(\theta))}{1+R^2+2R\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac12\log(1+R^2+2R\sin(\theta))  \right)\right|_{0}^{2\pi}+i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R(R+\sin(\theta))}{1+R^2+2R\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=0+i 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{R(R+\sin(\theta))}{1+R^2+2R\sin(\theta)}+\frac{R(R-\sin(\theta))}{1+R^2-2R\sin(\theta)}\right)\,d\theta\\\\
&=i2\, \left.\arctan\left(\frac{1+R\sin(\theta)}{R\cos(\theta)}\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}+i2\, \left.\arctan\left(\frac{1-R\sin(\theta)}{R\cos(\theta)}\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\\\\
&=i2\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-0\right)+i2\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \,\text{sgn}(1-R)-0\right)\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&,R<1\\\\
i2\pi&,R>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

---

**SECOND INTEGRAL**

For the second integral, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z-i|=R}\frac1{z+i}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2R\cos(\theta)+iR(R+2\sin(\theta))}{4+R^2+4R\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac12\log(4+R^2+4R\sin(\theta))  \right)\right|_{0}^{2\pi}\\\\
&+i2\, \left.\arctan\left(\frac{2+R\sin(\theta)}{R\cos(\theta)}\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}+i2\, \left.\arctan\left(\frac{2-R\sin(\theta)}{R\cos(\theta)}\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\\\\
&=i2\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-0\right)+i2\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \,\text{sgn}(2-R)-0\right)\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&,R<2\\\\
i2\pi&,R>2
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

---

**THIRD INTEGRAL**

For the third integral, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z-i|=R}\frac1{z-i}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\theta}}{Re^{i\theta}}\,d\theta\\\\
&=i2\pi
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it all together, we have

$$\oint_{|z-i|+R}\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz=
\begin{cases}
i2\pi &,R<1\\\\
i\pi&1<R<2\\\\
0&R>2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: could you please explain in the first integral how you went from $\displaystyle i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{R(R+\sin \theta)}{1+R^{2}+2R\sin \theta}d\theta$ to $\displaystyle i2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{R(R+\sin \theta)}{1+R^{2}+2R\sin \theta} + \frac{R(R-\sin \theta)}{1+R^{2}-2R\sin \theta}d\theta$? If that's an identity, I am unfamiliar with it. Also, I am unfamiliar with how you integrated $\displaystyle i2\int\frac{R(R+\sin \theta)}{1+R^{2}+2R \sin \theta}d \theta$ to get $\displaystyle i2 \arctan \left( \frac{1+R \sin \theta}{R \cos \theta}\right) + C$

Comment: $$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta&=\int_0^{\pi}f(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}f(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta\\\\&=\int_0^{\pi}f(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta+\int_0^{\pi}f(-\sin(\theta))\,d\theta\\\\&=\int_0^{\pi}(f(\sin(\theta))+f(-\sin(\theta))_\,d\theta\end{align}$$

Comment: okay, but what about the trig sub part that allows you to evaluate that integral to get $i2 \arctan \left(\frac{1+R \sin \theta}{R \cos \theta}\right)+C$? That gets a little wonky. Can you do it out?

Comment: For that integral, use the [Weierestrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).  It should be straightforward.  ;-))  - Mark

Comment: it's not. It's extremely complicated.

Comment: Jesse, how far did you get?  Have you read the section of the article in the link?

Comment: yes! Letting $\displaystyle \sin \theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}$ and $\displaystyle d \theta = \frac{2 dt}{1+t^{2}}$, the first integral becomes $\displaystyle \int\frac{R(R+\sin \theta}{1+R^{2}+2R\sin \theta} d\theta = \int \frac{R(R+\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}})}{1+R^{2}+2R\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}}\cdot \frac{2 dt}{1+t^{2}}$

Comment: which $\displaystyle = \int \frac{2(R^{2}+\frac{2tR}{1+t^{2}})}{\frac{1+t^{2} + R^{2} + R^{2}t^{2} + 2R 2t}{1+t^{2}}}\cdot \frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}$

Comment: OK. Now multiply numerator and denominator by $1+t^2$, complete the square in the denominator, and see if you can see the arctangent brewing.

Comment: $= \int \frac{2(R^{2} + \frac{2tR}{1+t^{2}}) dt}{1+t^{2}+R^{2} + R^{2}t^{2}+4Rt}$  Multiply numerator and denominator by $1+t^{2}$ NOW?

Comment: And Jesse, don't forget to use common sense. Before you make the substitution, see if you can rewrite the numerator to look like a constant plus another constant times the denominator.

Comment: THAT denominator?? No, I'm not seeing it. Please can you do some of this out for me?

Comment: I am just getting extremely frustrated!! I have no idea what you're talking about making sure before I make a substitution, see if you can rewrite the numerator to look like a constant plus another constant times the denominator.

Comment: that denominator is horrible, and I cannot see at all how to complete the square of it!

Comment: $R^2+R\sin(theta)=(1+R^2+2R\sin(\theta))/2+x$.  Solve for $x$ and now the substitution is facilitated.

Comment: Jesse, I'm on a smart phone and hada typo.  Read the comment again.

Comment: $\frac{R^{2}-1}{2} = x$. But, what is $x$? Did you mean $t$? Is this *the* $t$ from the substitutions I did above?

Comment: $x$ is the expression you found.  I need to go now.  You're smart and I'm confident that you can do this.  If not, just take the derivative of the arctangent expression and see that you will recover the integrand.  Bye for now.  -Mark

Comment: one more little thing. Why is $\arctan(1/R) = 0$ in that same integral?

Comment: also, I think your signum functions are backwards.

Comment: Jesse, the signum functions are correct as written.  What did you mean by "Why is $\arctan(1/R)=0$ ... " in the previous comment?  - Mark

Answer (score 1):

The first integral, $\int zdz = 0$ so we can ignore it
For the rest, use the fact that the winding number of a closed curve $C$ around $a$ is given by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z-a}$

Let $C$ be the circle $ |z-i| = R$ and $I$ be the integral we are calculating
For $R \gt 0$ we have $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z-i} = 1 \implies \int_C \frac{dz}{z-i} = 2\pi i$$ 
For $R \lt 1$ we have $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 0$$
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z+i} = 0$$
Therefore, for $R \lt 1$ we have $I = -\pi i$

For $1 \lt R \lt 2$ we have $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 1 \implies \int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i$$
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{z+i} = 0$$
Therefore, for $1 \lt R \lt 2$ we have $I = 2\pi i -\pi i = \pi i$

For $R \gt 2$ we have $$\displaystyle  \int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i$$
$$\displaystyle  \int_C \frac{dz}{z+i} = 2\pi i$$
Therefore, for $R \gt 2$ we have $I = 2\pi i -\pi i -\pi i = 0$